# Can't set lockscreen passcode

Tags: lock-screens

I have a Samsung Galaxy J4. A few days ago, I suddenly was not able to unlock the screen of my phone. I don't recall doing anything special with it before that happened.

After some searching and playing with adb, I removed the files `/data/system/locksettings.*`, and `/data/system_de/0/spblob/`. And I was able to clear the screenlocker and get in to my phone.

However, when I tried to set a screenlocker again, the following error message appears in logcat:

```
04-29 14:00:47.103  3083  4440 I SyntheticPasswordManager: Device does not support weaver
04-29 14:00:47.109  2757  2757 D gatekeeperd: enroll ret = -1
04-29 14:00:47.111  3083  4440 E SyntheticPasswordManager: Fail to enroll user password when creating SP for user 0
04-29 14:00:47.114  3083  4440 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system_de/0/spblob/0000000000000000.handle: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 14:00:47.117  2757  2757 D gatekeeperd: enroll ret = -1
04-29 14:00:47.118  3083  4440 E SyntheticPasswordManager: Fail to create new SID for user 0
04-29 14:00:47.119  3083  4440 D LockPatternUtils: isCredentialRequiredToUnlockUser: 1
04-29 14:00:47.119  3083  4440 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system_de/0/spblob/0000000000000000.handle: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

After that, it would appear like if there is no lockscreen set in the settings menu. But if I turn off the screen and on again, there would be one. Attempting to unlock gives the following errors:

```
04-29 14:03:01.453  3083  3083 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 14:03:02.770  3083  5292 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/password.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 14:03:02.771  3083  5292 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gatekeeper.gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 14:03:02.771  3083  5292 E LockSettingsStorage: Cannot read file java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/system/gesture.key: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-29 14:03:02.771  3083  5292 E LockSettingsService: doVerifyCredential type mismatch with stored credential?? stored: -1 passed in: 2
```

It seems like the passcode was not properly saved. After reading the [source code of SyntheticPasswordManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-8.0.0_r4/services/core/java/com/android/server/SyntheticPasswordManager.java#273), I'm guessing it's caused by the `gatekeeperd: enroll ret = -1` error, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help on how to continue debug this problem is appreciated.

Comment: I foudn that `spblob` directory regenerates itself. But even after putting the files I removed from `spblob` directory back, it puts me back to the original state where I can't unlock even with correct passcode. The phone won't lock up after 5 incorrect retries, though. It's back to normal after wiping data partition, so I'm pretty sure the problem came from missing files or wrong setting values.

Comment: only delete locksettings.db + wal + shm